# Hyperlink JQuery doesn't triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, html-table

I'm using JQuery for adding table row and at the last column I have hyperlink for cancel/delete the row. But it seems my JQuery not triggered when I clicked the hyperlink. Here my code:

```
$('input[name=barcode]').change(function() {
    var newRow = $("<td><a href='#' class='remove'><font color='0404B4'>Cancel</font></a></td>");
    $('#tab > tbody > tr').eq(index).after(newRow);
});
$(".remove").click(function() {
    //delete row
    alert("b");
});
```

Comment: You need to use event delegation as the element is inserted in to the DOM after the handler is attached - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You have to delegate event: `$('#tab').on('click', '.remove', function(){...});`

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: It's work guys, sorry i'm new to Jquery, thanks for the clue mate....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not triggered since the newly added element is not bound to the click event. You can try this code:

```
$('#tab').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    alert('b');
});
```

You can get more info over here [jQuery on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)